# Sql query has unwanted results - Where is the problem?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which records users's scores at a game (a user may submit 5,10,20,as many scores as he wants).
I need to show the 20 top scores of a game, but per user. (as a user may have submitted eg 4 scores which are the top according to other users's scores)
The query i have written is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `table_highscores`.`userkey`,
    max(`table_highscores`.`score`),
    `table_users`.`username`,
    `table_highscores`.`dateachieved` 
FROM
    `table_highscores`, `table_users` 
WHERE
    `table_highscores`.`userkey` = `table_users`.`userkey`
AND
    `table_highscores`.`gamekey` = $gamekey  
GROUP BY
    `userkey` 
ORDER BY
    max(`table_highscores`.`score`) DESC,
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

The output result is ok, but there is a problem. When i calculate the difference of days (today-this of `dateachieved`) the result is wrong. (eg instead of saying "the score was submitted 22 days ago, it says 43 days ago) So,I have to do a second query for each score so to find the true date (meaning +20 queries). Is there any shorter way to find the correct date?
 Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely true it's the query that has 'unwanted' results, or is your calculation off? What does `dateachieved` look like (a DATETIME?) and how are you calculating the difference? To me, it seems that the problem has nothing to do with the query itself.

Comment: Is it possible for a user to submit the same high score more than once on different dates? If there are multiple dates with the same maximum score, do you want the date fo the oldest or the most recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you should use an explicit JOIN and you don't need the DISTINCT keyword.

This query should solve your problem. I am assuming here that it is possible for a user to submit the same highscore more than once on different dates, and if that happens then you want the oldest date:

```
SELECT T1.userkey, T1.score, username, dateachieved FROM (
    (SELECT userkey, max(score) AS score
    FROM table_highscores
    WHERE gamekey = $gamekey
    GROUP BY userkey) AS T1
    JOIN
    (SELECT userkey, score, min(dateachieved) as dateachieved
    FROM table_highscores
    WHERE gamekey = $gamekey
    GROUP BY userkey, score) AS T2
    ON T1.userkey = T2.userkey AND T1.score = T2.score
) JOIN table_users ON T1.userkey = table_users.userkey
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: thank you very much! I found OMG Ponies's too complicated to understand so i used your's. :) 
To answer other questions (in case someone else has the same problem), dateachieved is stored as yyyy-mm-dd. The calculation of days is done by this way: ceil(abs((strtotime("$dateachieved_from_the_query") - strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) / (60 * 60 * 24)));
Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: Are you storing the dateachieved as a string instead of a datetime or similar? It would be better to choose an appropriate type for the coumn, then you could just do it as OMG Ponies suggested: `DATEDIFF(NOW(), hs.dateachieved)`. Did you try that? Did it give an error?

Answer (score 3):

> there is a problem. When i calculate the difference of days (today-this of dateachieved) the result is wrong.

There's two issues

1. the `dateachieved` isn't likely to be the value associated with the high score
2. you can use [MySQL's DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to return the the number of days between the current date and the `dateachieved` value.

Use:

```
SELECT u.username,
       hs.userkey,
       hs.score,
       DATEDIFF(NOW(), hs.dateachieved) 
  FROM TABLE_HIGHSCORES hs
  JOIN TABLE_USERNAME u ON u.userkey = hs.userkey
  JOIN (SELECT ths.userkey,
               ths.gamekey,
               ths.max_score,
               MAX(ths.date_achieved) 'max_date'
          FROM TABLE_HIGHSCORES ths
          JOIN (SELECT t.userkey,
                       t.gamekey,
                       MAX(t.score) 'max_score'
                  FROM TABLE_HIGHSCORES t
              GROUP BY t.userkey, t.gamekey) ms ON ms.userkey = ths.userkey
                                               AND ms.gamekey = ths.gamekey
                                               AND ms.max_score = ths.score
       ) x ON x.userkey = hs.userkey
          AND x.gamekey = hs.gamekey
          AND x.max_score = hs.score
          AND x.max_date = hs.dateachieved
 WHERE hs.gamekey = $gamekey
 ORDER BY hs.score DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

I also changed your query to use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, from ANSI-89 syntax.  It's equivalent performance, but it's easier to read, syntax is supported on Oracle/SQL Server/Postgres/etc, and provides consistent LEFT JOIN support.

Another thing - you only need to use backticks when tables and/or column names are MySQL keywords.

Comment: You have a comma too many after max_score, the username table is called table_users, and in the group by userkey and gamekey the alias is t, not hs.

Comment: @Mark: Corrected, thanks.  I also updated to cover getting the most current max score value based on date.

Comment: I returned the oldest in my query. I think that makes more sense because if you get the same highscore as someone else then you want bragging rights that you were the first to achieve that highscore. But in the end it's up to the poster to decide what they want - it's easy to change both our queries to return either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what language you are using to calculate the difference but I'm guessing it's PHP because of the `$gamekey` you used there (which should be escaped properly, btw).

If your dateachieved field is in the DATETIME format, you can calculate the difference like this:

```
$diff = round((time() - strtotime($row['dateachieved'])) / 86400);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify your question a little better. Can you provide some data and expected outputs and then I should be able to help you further?

Comment: Ask for clarifications in the comments, not in an actual answer, as you are not answering to anything yet.